# Executing different functions on [RETURN] keypress from different text fields

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have two text fields:

```
@IBOutlet weak var loginEmailInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var loginPasswordInput: UITextField!
```

When the `loginEmailInput` is active and the return key is pressed, I just want to close the keyboard:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(loginEmailInput: UITextField) -> Bool {
    loginEmailInput.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

When the `loginPasswordInput` is active and the return key is pressed, I want to also execute the function `loginButtonPressed(...)`:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(loginPasswordInput: UITextField) -> Bool {
    loginPasswordInput.resignFirstResponder()
    loginButtonPressed(self)
    return true
}
```

However, I receive an error stating that I've now redeclared the `textFieldShouldReturn` function:

> Invalid redeclaration of 'textFieldShouldReturn'

How can I handle the `[return]` key being pressed with different text fields active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the function once and branch depending on the given `sender`:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(sender: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if sender == loginEmailInput {
        sender.resignFirstResponder() // or loginEmailInput.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    } else if sender == loginPasswordInput {
        sender.resignFirstResponder() // or loginPasswordInput.resignFirstResponder()
        loginButtonPressed(self)
        return true
    }
}
```

Alternatively use a switch case:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(sender: UITextField) -> Bool {
    switch sender {
    case loginEmailInput:
        sender.resignFirstResponder() // or loginEmailInput.resignFirstResponder()
    case loginPasswordInput:
        sender.resignFirstResponder() // or loginPasswordInput.resignFirstResponder()
        loginButtonPressed(self)
    default:
        break
    }
    return true
}
```

If you want to remove as much redundancy as possible you could even use:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(sender: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if sender == loginPasswordInput {
        loginButtonPressed(self)
    }
    return true
}
```

The reason the `textFieldShouldReturn` gets a `sender` passed along is exactly for this kind of situations. It is a common pattern for delegates functions to get the object passed along from where the delegate methods gets invoked to make the receiver respond to multiple instances at once.

Comment: Where is `textField` defined? I tried running this and pressing `return` on both, but neither did anything.

Comment: @Ben `textField` is the parameter of the function.

Comment: Previously it worked using the name of the text field name (e.g. `loginPasswordInput`), however using `textField` it doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: @Ben did you set your controller or whatever as the delegate of both textfields?

Comment: Ah - that was the problem! Thank you!

Comment: Great Answer!!. Apologies for a bad answer earlier on from my side @Ben

Comment: @luk2302 Thank you for adding the detail about `sender`, it's helped me understand the functions in Swift a whole lot more.

Comment: @Ben happy to help!